# Passing Data to Web Component

Tags: typescript, stenciljs

I have the following web component:

```
import { Component, h, Element, Prop } from '@stencil/core';
import { Schedule } from '../../interfaces/schedule';

@Component({
    tag: 'event-schedules-tab',
    styleUrl: 'event-schedules-tab.css'
})
export class EventSchedulesTab {
    /**
       * The first name
       */
    @Prop() schedules: Schedule[];
    @Element() element: HTMLElement;

    componentDidLoad() {
        this.displayTickets();
    }

    displayTickets() {
        if (this.schedules !== undefined) {
            let divSchedules: HTMLDivElement = this.element.querySelector("#schedules");
            for (let i = 0; i < this.schedules.length; i++) {
                let eventSchedule = document.createElement("event-schedule");
                eventSchedule.schedule = this.schedules[i];
                divSchedules.appendChild(eventSchedule);
            }
            console.log("schedules is defined");
        }

        console.log("display schedules");
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <div id="schedules" class="bg-gray-100"></div>
        ];
    }
}
```

Now inside another web component I have this tag displayed:

```
import { Component, h, Prop, Element } from '@stencil/core';
import { EventItem } from '../../interfaces/event-item';
import { Event } from '../../services/event'

@Component({
    tag: 'event-details',
    styleUrl: 'event-details.css'
})
export class EventDetails {
    /**
        * The first name
        */
    @Prop() slug: string;
    @Element() element: HTMLElement;
    private eventsService: Event = new Event();

    componentDidLoad() {

        this.displayEvent();

    }

    async displayEvent() {
        if (this.slug !== undefined) {
            this.eventsService.fetchTickets(this.slug).then(async (response) => {
                let event: EventItem = await response.json();

                let thumbnail: HTMLElement = this.element.querySelector(".modal .thumbnail");
                thumbnail.setAttribute("src", event.banners[0]);

                let category: HTMLElement = this.element.querySelector(".modal .category");
                category.innerText = event.category;

                let title: HTMLElement = this.element.querySelector(".modal .title");
                title.innerText = event.name;

                let description: HTMLElement = this.element.querySelector(".modal .description");
                description.innerText = event.description;

                let eventSchedulesTab: HTMLEventSchedulesTabElement = this.element.querySelector("event-schedules-tab");
                eventSchedulesTab.schedules = event.schedules;

                let eventSummaryTab = this.element.querySelector("event-summary-tab");
                eventSummaryTab.summary = event.description;

                //console.log(event);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <div class="flex flex-col">
                <event-schedules-tab></event-schedules-tab>
                <event-summary-tab></event-summary-tab>
            </div>
        ];
    }

}
```

When an my event-details component loads, data is fetched from my server and the response is assigned to my event-schedules-tab component:

```
let eventSchedulesTab: HTMLEventSchedulesTabElement = this.element.querySelector("event-schedules-tab");
eventSchedulesTab.schedules = event.schedules;
```

Now my issue is for some reason after this code is executed the schedules property in my event-schedules-tab always shows as undefined.

I have confirmed that the right response is being returned from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you use componentDidLoad in "EventSchedulesTab", but when you are using it there is no "schedules" defined, then the didload method executes without result, then when you change the property but no function is executed except render.
You could use a @Watch to schedules to execute desired function

Or also you can make render depending of that property like:

```
render() {
  return (<div id="schedules" class="bg-gray-100">{this.schedules.map((s) => <event-schedule schedule={s}></event-schedule>)}</div>)
}
```

This will make your code reactive to property change because if the "schedules" property will change, render will be executed

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem exactly, fixed it, works now! :)